# C# SQL => operator meaning

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Using C# SQL in LINQ, I came across this statement:

```
var names = database.Browsers.Select(b => b.Name);
```

What does `b=>b.Name` do?  What does the `=>` operator do in general?

The code is part of C#.net framework where database is a handle on the underlying database via Linq.

Comment: It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `=>` indicates the use of a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  In this case `b` is a reference to an instance of the Browser object, while the `Select(b=> b.Name)` will return an enumerable containing only the attribute `Name`.